# Frequency estimation algorithm with only one cycle

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing, frequency-analysis

I need to compute the fundamental frequency of three-phasor in DSP unit. I have a sample frequency of 256 kHz and fundamental frequency expected about 50Hz. Which algorithm I need in order to compute the frequency with one cycle of the signal and error less of 1%?

Comment: I would try to export the ADC data to try out approaches. E.g. if you multiply a frequency input with an expected frequency sine wave you get a slow beat frequency. (Under the condition your time normal is stable enough)

Comment: what is the shape of your signal (can you add image or even better also sampled values of at least 2.5 periods), how noisy or repeatable it is? for simple shapes you can just measure distance between crossings of certain level (like avg value), or between max or between min, for more complex shapes you can either use FFT or brute force + correlation coefficient or abs distance between periods. The data is int or float ?